# comparison operators - how to compare 3 values in php

Tags: php

Hi can anyone help me solve below problem, i want compare below values

example `$a=10; $b=12; $c=11;` if $c is less then or equal to $a and $b greater then or equal to $c, if $c is between the value display yes,

```
$a = 10;
$b = 12;
$c = ?;

if($b <= $c >= $a){
   echo "yes";
}
```

help me with code correction

Comment: What's wrong with just doing it the way you wrote in your comment? `$c <= $a and $b >= $c`.

Comment: If there is a DB question here please add it. (you probably can do all the checking at the DB level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got solution thank you every one

```
$a = 10;
$b = 12;
$c = 11;

if($c>=$a && $c<=$b ){
   echo "yes";
}
```

Comment: this is not how SO works, you took help from peoples answer but you dont upvote when you have the priviledge ?? this is unfair, either delete the question or else upvote the answers from which you got help

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just use &&?

i.e.

```
if($c <= $a && $b <= $c)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
if($c<=$a && $b>=c ){
   echo "";
}
```